# Access value of useState in theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, use-state

I am building a React NextJS application with MaterialUI. I have a header component with a switch that I basically want to use to toggle between dark and light mode in my theme file (separate file). Basically, my question is how it is possible for me to basically get the value of the useState that I use on the Switch in my Theme file to change between dark and light mode.
Thank you!
~Max

[image: Header.tsx(logic)]

[image: theme.tsx]

**Edit 2: Example on stackblitz**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hmqdnk?file=NavBar.tsx

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.. please provide code, when you're asking to reproduce... and mention user to mention, i guess...

Comment: Thanks for adding the links to your code. More context would be helpful as its unclear what the component tree looks like for your case. Consider creating a simplified example on https://stackblitz.com/ and linking it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that returns dark or light theme depending on the function parameter that would be the value of the Switch component.

```
const getTheme = (light) => {
    let lightTheme = {
        palette: {
            type: 'light',
        }
    }

    let darkTheme = {
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
        }
    }
    
    return createMuiTheme(light ? lightTheme : darkTheme)
}
```